# Detecting TAB keypress and making the script execution conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following script

```
   $('.formfield:not(.NoHighlight, #P_PH_PHONE, #P120_PH_EMAIL) :input').focus(function(e){


            var currentElementonForm = $(this); 
            if(currentElementonForm.is("input[type=submit]")){
                currentElementonForm.parents('form').submit();
            }

    });
```

Currently, the page submits when a user tabbed (keyborad TAB button) to the submit button. I would like to stop this but only do it when a user clicked not tabbed to the button. Hopefully, the question is clear and happy to give anymore details. I did try detecting e.keyCode == 9 but it logs it as "undefined".

Comment: Does this question help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762594/jquery-keyup-for-tab-key

Comment: e.keyCode comes as "undefined" failing to identify the event keycode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find an alternative way to deal with this issue. The problem was on "`focus`" event does not return a `keyCode` even when using the TAB key. So had to work with a different solution. This was something new to me and hopefully this might benefit someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Edit : Since keyCode is not working we can approach this problem differently ?

```
$('.formfield input[type=submit]').click( function() {
      $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
```

---

```
  $('.formfield:not(.NoHighlight, #P_PH_PHONE, #P120_PH_EMAIL) :input').focus(function(e){
            var currentElementonForm = $(this); 
            if(currentElementonForm.is("input[type=submit]")){
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code !== 9) {
                    currentElementonForm.parents('form').submit();
                }

            }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks.. but e.keyCode results as "undefined"

Comment: The problem is keyCode doesn't trigger when on "focus" event.