# When to use PreventDefault( ) vs Return false?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

Firstly, in JavaScript's event model, you will come
across a concept called as event bubbling
(which makes an event to propagate from child
element to a parent element). In order to avoid
such kind of bubbling effect, many developers
use an event method called `stopPropagation( )`.
Alternatively, developers have started to use
`return false` statement to stop such propagation.
Now, there is another terminology called
`preventDefault( )`. As the name indicates, this
method prevents any default behavior of an
element to trigger. Best use case is to prevent an
anchor tag to open a link.

You may come across a scenario where you
would like to prevent the anchor tag from
opening a link (default behavior) as well as stop
the event from going up to the parent.
In such situation, instead of writing two lines of code,
you can get it done in single line i.e; `return false`

Comment: This is a great topic to cover, but needs to be in a question and answer format. Also, there's already a good question with good answers on this topic, which I've marked here.

Comment: This will be helpful too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: The content in this question seems to be coming from a company's blog. This post is probably well intended, but it is not in a question-answer format, and it doesn't cite the source either.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it address the "return false" instruction specifically which is not the case in the top link dup question.

Comment: I hope there is an option to downvote those moderators.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMartin FWIW there are answers under the target that also cover return false quite comprehensively.

Answer (score 186):

**return false;**

---

`return false;` does 3 separate things when you call it:

1. `event.preventDefault()` – It stops the browsers default behaviour.
2. `event.stopPropagation()` – It prevents the event from propagating (or “bubbling up”) the DOM.
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, `return false` does not stop the event from bubbling up.

**preventDefault();**

---

`preventDefault();` does one thing: It stops the browsers default behaviour.

**When to use them?**

---

We know what they do but when to use them? Simply it depends on what you want to accomplish. Use `preventDefault();` if you want to “just” prevent the default browser behaviour. Use return false; when you want to prevent the default browser behaviour and prevent the event from propagating the DOM. In most situations where you would use return false; what you really want is `preventDefault()`.

**Examples:**

---

Let’s try to understand with examples:

We will see pure JAVASCRIPT example

**Example 1:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> Run the above code you will see the hyperlink **‘Click here to visit
>   stackoverflow.com‘** now if you click on that link first you will get
>   the javascript alert **Link Clicked** Next you will get the javascript
>   alert **div Clicked** and immediately you will be redirected to
>   stackoverflow.com.

**Example 2:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> Run the above code you will see the hyperlink ‘Click here to visit
>   stackoverflow.com‘ now if you click on that link first you will get
>   the javascript alert **Link Clicked** Next you will get the javascript
>   alert **div Clicked** Next you will see the hyperlink ‘Click here to
>   visit stackoverflow.com‘ replaced by the text ‘Click event prevented‘
>   and you will **not** be redirected to stackoverflow.com. This is due > to event.preventDefault() method we used to prevent the default click
>   action to be triggered.

**Example 3:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event is going to be executed'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> This time if you click on Link the function executeParent() will not
>   be called and you will not get the javascript alert **div Clicked**
>   this time. This is due to us having prevented the propagation to the
>   parent div using event.stopPropagation() method. Next you will see the
>   hyperlink ‘Click here to visit stackoverflow.com‘ replaced by the text
>   ‘Click event is going to be executed‘ and immediately you will be
>   redirected to stackoverflow.com. This is because we haven’t prevented
>   the default click action from triggering this time using
>   event.preventDefault() method.

**Example 4:**

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('Div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

> If you click on the Link, the function executeParent() will not be
>   called and you will not get the javascript alert. This is due to us
>   having prevented the propagation to the parent div using
>   event.stopPropagation() method. Next you will see the hyperlink ‘Click
>   here to visit stackoverflow.com‘ replaced by the text ‘Click event
>   prevented‘ and you will not be redirected to stackoverflow.com. This
>   is because we have prevented the default click action from triggering
>   this time using event.preventDefault() method.

**Example 5:**

> **For return false I have three examples and all appear to be doing the exact same thing (just returning false), but in reality the
>   results are quite different. Here's what actually happens in each of
>   the above.**

cases:

1. Returning **false** from an inline event handler prevents the browser from navigating to the link address, but it doesn't stop the event from propagating through the DOM.
2. Returning **false** from a jQuery event handler prevents the browser from navigating to the link address and it stops the event from propagating through the DOM.
3. Returning **false** from a regular DOM event handler does absolutely nothing.

Will see all three example.

1. Inline return false.

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com' onclick='return false'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  var link = document.querySelector('a');

  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented using inline html'
    alert('Link Clicked');
  });


  function executeParent() {
    alert('Div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

2. Returning **false** from a jQuery event handler.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  $('a').click(function(event) {
    alert('Link Clicked');
    $('a').text('Click event prevented using return FALSE');
    $('a').contents().unwrap();
    return false;
  });
  $('div').click(function(event) {
    alert('Div clicked');
  });
</script>
```

3. Returning false from a regular DOM event handler.

```html
<div onclick='executeParent()'>
  <a href='http://stackoverflow.com' onclick='executeChild()'>Click here to visit stackoverflow.com</a>
</div>
<script>
  function executeChild() {
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'Click event prevented'
    alert('Link Clicked');
    return false
  }

  function executeParent() {
    alert('Div Clicked');
  }
</script>
```

Hope these examples are clear. Try executing all these examples in a html file to see how they work.

Comment: in the first example, why does the parent's function run first before the child? if it the event has to propagate up, shouldn't it hit the child's function first? or does the event go up as part of the stack and resolve downwards, resulting in the parent's function to be run first and then the child?

Comment: return false from the event handler doesn't do event.stopPropagation() apparently from this [codepen here](http://codepen.io/paramsinghvc/pen/ENOvLE?editors=1011)
 @keval-bhatt

Comment: -1, `return false` seems not to do (in FF51, Chrome 56 and IE11, where I tried) those things you mention. Please add references to back it up.

Comment: The explanation of preventDefault() vs stopPropagation() is excellent (I finally understand!), but the `return false` part seems to be wrong as @Sz points out-- still observed on chrome 58.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-a-click-event-listener#answer-128966

Comment: @DonHatch Now check I removed jquery and updated answer with pure javascript now take look for return false example.

Comment: @akantoword in old example i mixed jquery and javascript both to gather so that is why its not working correctly now you can check the example your will get clear idea.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is corrected, your explanation is great and really thorough, and these examples are a great way to answer a question so people can readily verify your claims.  Changing to +1, very nice!

Comment: This answer is no longer correct: https://jsfiddle.net/ts0t9yLa/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum have you read example 5.2 and 5.3?

In example 5.2 I mention return false will work for jquery event, and example 5.3 is same as what you posted.

Let me know if you have any question?

Comment: Yes, 5.1 and 5.3 don't work anymore (that's the fiddle). I __definitely__ remember them working or am confused about it :)

Comment: It's hard to tell what this answer is talking about-- first it claims that "return false" means a certain thing, but then it says that's different from "normal" (non-jquery) behavior... but we were never talking about jquery to begin with, as far as I can see.