# preventDefault vs return false when it comes to reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started learning Reactjs today and found an interesting fact (and din't find any relevant topic) that we must use `preventDefault` than using `return false` statement to prevent the default behavior: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

But as far as I know, return false is equivalent to (from jQuery background):

```
// e.preventDefault();
// e.stopPropagation();
// stop function execution after return false
// stops the callback function
```

But I'm curious to know here how react has implemented so that we cannot use `return false` statement and we must use `preventDefault` to prevent the default behavior.

So, what's exactly difference between `preventDefault` and `return false` when it comes to reactjs? Why `preventDefault` is more robust than `return false` in reactjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `return false` in the DOM, it has some "magical" behavior which is implicit instead of explicit.  When you register an event callback in React, you are *not* explicitly setting an event handler in the DOM because React is an abstraction to the DOM.  React elements are part of a "virtual DOM" and you are no longer working directly with the DOM, therefore event handlers have layers of abstraction between your component handler and the DOM element itself.

Could React have implemented their API in such a way that `return false;` mirrored this implicit behavior?  Perhaps.  But they have their own API and clearly chose not to.

Here is a [good overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473581/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false) of how the DOM handles things when you `return false`.

Comment: I still need to deep dive into react so that I can know how everything actually works...

Answer (score 4):

The events in react are not the native events of the browser, they are wrapped for your convenience.

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a
>   cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the
>   same interface as the browser’s native event, including
>   stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work
>   identically across all browsers.

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

So when you do preventDefault, you are not calling the method of the native event directly, but instead, react takes care of you.

So returning false is returning false to reacts event and not the native event one, meaning, it doesn't really do anything...

Comment: Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually using `return false` from event handlers to prevent the default behavior [has been deprecated](https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html#deprecations) since React 0.12.

So it's not an option of the most robust choice, you just can't use `return false` for this purpose in `React`.

You must call the event `preventDefault` explicitly, [as explained in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).