# How to remove multi request method in yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to update data in detailView row using Kartik Editable as inline editing, and I'm using Kartik detailView. Because of the data not sent manually so I send the data through ***ajax*** with method **post**,
this is my view.php:

```
<?php
echo DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'mode' => DetailView::MODE_VIEW,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'busFleetStatus',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => Editable::widget([
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'busFleetStatus',
                'beforeInput' => function($form, $widget) {
                    echo $form->field($widget->model, 'busFleetStatus')->widget(\kartik\select2\Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(SystemStatus::find()->where(['statusCode' => 'busFleetStatus'])->all(), 'systemStatusId', 'statusDetail'),
                    ])->label(false);
                },
                'afterInput' => function($form, $widget) {
                    echo $form->field($widget->model, 'busFleetStatus')->widget(\kartik\select2\Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(SystemStatus::find()->where(['statusDetail' => 'busFleetStatus'])->all(), 'systemStatusId', 'statusDetail'),
                    ])->label(false);
                },
                'size' => 'lg',
                'header' => 'Bus Fleet Status',
                'displayValueConfig' => [
                    1 => 'Operating',
                    2 => 'Maintenance',
                    3 => 'Available',
                    4 => 'Booked',
                ],
                'placement' => 'right',                            
                'format' => Editable::FORMAT_LINK,
                'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_SELECT2,
                'showAjaxErrors' => false,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                ],
            ]),
        ],
    ],
])
?>
```

and this is my ajax:

```
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['bus-fleet/view?id=' . $model->busFleetId]);
$key = $model->busFleetId;
$this->registerJs(<<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.kv-editable-submit').click(function() {               

    var key = '$key';
    var parAtt = $(".popover-title").clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text();               

    var preRep = parAtt.replace(/^\s+Edit /,"");

    var postRepF = preRep.replace(/\s+$/, "");

    var postRepS = postRepF.replace(/\s+/, "");        

    var upAtt = postRepS.replace(/\s+/, "");        

    var value = $("#select2-busfleet-busfleetstatus-container").text();

    var att = upAtt[0].toLowerCase() + upAtt.substring(1)

    $.ajax({     
        url: '$url',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{hasEditable: 1, editableIndex: 0, editableKey: key, BusFleet: [{name: value, editableAttribute: att}]},
        type: 'post',
    });     
});
});
JS
);
?>
```

the ajax update the data successfully with method **POST**, but in sametime it show *json parse error* because the manual method **GET** also execute.
So I have two request in sametime when I clicked the button
[image]

How do I can remove the GET method request? I need only the POST request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you want to prevent the default behaviour of `.kv-editable-submit`

```
$('.kv-editable-submit').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();

    // your custom code goes here

    return false;        
}
```

also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473685/374509) on event propagation for a more in-depth explanation

Comment: Hi thanks for the respond, I've try yours but give me nothing :(