# return false; and preventDefault(); not working. Onclick redirects to image link url

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an action on the product images (below main image) that when the user clicks on the Right Arrow, the 5th image will be clicked automatically and it will be shown as the main image. Here's the link for reference: http://sazua.apleu.servertrust.com/3B-Scientific-Classic-Brain-5-part-p/c18.htm

I've tried return false; and preventDefault(); but the click is still redirecting the user to the next image url link.

HTML:

```html
<li class="current">
    <a style="display: none;" href="/v/vspfiles/photos/C18-6.jpg" rel="shadowbox[ProductImages]" title="Classic Human Brain, 5 part" data-sbkey="5">
        <img class="vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo" id="alternate_product_photo_6" style="border-color:#666666;" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/C18-6S.jpg" border="1" onclick="javascript:change_product_photo(6);return false;">
    </a>
    <a href="/v/vspfiles/photos/C18-6.jpg" data-sbkey="5" title="Classic Human Brain, 5 part">
        <img class="vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo" id="alternate_product_photo_6" style="border-color:#666666;" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/C18-6S.jpg" border="1" onclick="javascript:change_product_photo(6);return false;">
    </a>
</li>
```

Javascript I'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right-btn-carousel").click(function (e) {
       $("#altviews > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(2) > img").click();
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Note: I can't modify the HTML since I'm using Volusion (hardcoded) so I'm trying to work with what I have.

Thanks.

Comment: preventDefault before anything else is called

Comment: When you say 'the 5th image will be clicked automatically' what behavior are you expecting the user to experience with this image is clicked?

Comment: What is the full HTML tag that has the ID `right-btn-carousel`?

Comment: @silencedogood The 5th image should be selected as the main image (bigger image)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk <img id="right-btn-carousel" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/arrow-right.png" class="next">

Comment: @KevinHernandez How do I do that before the function is called?

Comment: put `preventDefault()` at the top of the function call, the first thing that should run should be `e.preventDefault(0`

Comment: @KevinHernandez This? $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right-btn-carousel").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
$("#altviews > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(2) > img").click();
     
  });
});

Comment: Yes just like that

Comment: @KevinHernandez Tried that. Didn't make any difference. :(

Comment: Anybody else? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use e.preventDefault() e.stopImmediatePropagation() before any action/side effects inside click method. I meant first step.

Try to empty your `<a href="#" />` if href is not needed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right-btn-carousel").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     $("#altviews > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(1) > a").attr("href", "#"); 
      $("#altviews > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(2) > img").click();
     ;
   });
});
```

Comment: To add on to this, you should know the difference between `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. The former is used to stop any action _on the element you are clicking_ while the latter stops the click event from 'bubbling' up the DOM tree. So you can click on the arrow without also clicking on the image. 

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473581/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false/30473685

Comment: I got that. Still no success. I'm using: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right-btn-carousel").click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    $("#altviews > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(2) > img").click();
  });
});

Comment: Try to remove or update "href" of <a> to "#" like <a href="#" />  - $("#altviews > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(1) > a").attr("href", "#"); before triggering image click

Comment: Let me know if this helps

Comment: It gave me a few ideas. I'm trying a few things. Will let you know.

Comment: That's so weird. I've removed both <a>'s and it's still being redirected? Do you think the onclick="javascript:change_product_photo(6);return false;" inside the <img> is messing with that?

Comment: Ok. I was able to replace all the href with #. But every time I click it goes to the top of the page. How do I remove that? Making the link null?

Comment: javascript:void(0); fixed it. Thanks a LOT!