# How using comma character like enter in input at React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to make tag input and when user type ',' character i wan't to add entry to input

i use for it like that function on onKeyDown

```
inputKeydown = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    var patt = /^[0-9]*$/;
    if (e.key === "Enter" ||  e.which === 188 && val) {
      let a = this.state.zips.includes(val);
      if (
        this.state.tags.find(
          tag => tag.value.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase()
        )
      ) {
        return;
      }
      if (val.length != 5) {
        return;
      }
      this.setState({ tags: [...this.state.tags, { match: a, value: val }] });
      this.tagInput.value = null;
    } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && !val) {
      this.removeTag(this.state.tags.length - 1);
    }
  };
```

here is if user press to enter entry goes to **this.state.tags** array here i wan't to do if user type ',' will be same action.

i used for that

```
e.which === 188
```

everything works well but this add to input ',' character too. 
i don't wan't to show ',' character in input what i need to do ?

Comment: just use `.replace` and remove `,`

Comment: where exactly ?

Comment: did you try to put `e.preventDefault()` at the start of your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preventDefault()` method. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> This method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, **its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.**

So:

```js
inputKeydown = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    var patt = /^[0-9]*$/;
    if (e.key === "Enter" ||  e.which === 188 && val) {
      e.preventDefault(); // ---> This will prevent putting a comma.
      let a = this.state.zips.includes(val);
      if (
        this.state.tags.find(
          tag => tag.value.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase()
        )
      ) {
        return;
      }
      if (val.length != 5) {
        return;
      }
      this.setState({ tags: [...this.state.tags, { match: a, value: val }] });
      this.tagInput.value = null;
    } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && !val) {
      this.removeTag(this.state.tags.length - 1);
    }
  };
```

You also could have use `return false` which does the same thing with some additional stuff. Please see [this great response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473581/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false/30473685#30473685) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in your condition so that the default event (inserting a comma) is not triggered

```js
document.getElementById('textinput').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.which === 188){
    alert('comma')
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textinput" />
```