# How can you cancel a customEvent, if preventDefault() only prevents default browser action?

Tags: javascript

```js
const log = console.log;

const child = document.getElementById('child');
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');


parent.addEventListener('newColor', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault()
    log('parent')
    this.style.color = e.detail.textColor;
})

child.addEventListener('newColor', function(e) { 
    log('child')
    this.style.color = e.detail.textColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor = e.detail.bgrColor;
})


function changeColor() { 
    const myEvent = new CustomEvent('newColor', { 
        detail: { 
            textColor: 'red',
            bgrColor: 'blue',
        },
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: true
    })

    child.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}


changeColor()
```

```html
<p id="parent">this is the parent<span id="child"> THIS IS THE CHILD ELEMENT </span></p>
```

Since `event.preventDefault()` only prevent the default browser action, how can a custom Event be 'canceled' then?

For example, in here:

```js
$("#but").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    alert('child button clicked');
  })
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>


<button id="but">button</button>
```

the `preventDefault()` only prevents the default action, which would be to submit a form, not the execution of the rest of the function statements.

So, what is the point of having 'cancellable' property when you can't actually cancel a event with `preventDefault()`?

Comment: Maybe "return"?

Comment: `return` does not cancel an event, and therefore `cancellable` property has no effect on it.

Comment: What you describe is precisely the semantics of Events. They can't really be "cancelled", because they're events (something *has* happened), not commands (demanding that something happen). The "cancellable" property is an unfortunate misnomer. Kinda like how you can't cancel a Promise, but you can try to abort the process that returned it.

Comment: @Touffy So, what can you 'cancel' then? Can you please give me some simple basic example? In `w3schools`, they say that `cancellable` prevents the `preventDefault()` from cancelling the event ,but that's not true, is it? So, when I set the `cancellable` to `false`, what stops working on it? What does it prevent exactly? I just need some basic example to get it.

Comment: Then w3schools is not as inaccurate as it used to ;) so yeah, "cancellable" should really be named "defaultPreventable" because that's what it does. You're not telling the browser that the event (click, keypress, form submission…) didn't happen, only that it shouldn't do the default action associated with it, if any. Your own listeners will be able to react to the event anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you call `Event.preventDefault()` on a browser-provided object, for example:

```
document.querySelector("#id-checkbox").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     console.log("run") // This is still run
     event.preventDefault()
});
```

It will not trigger browser-defined default action like checking the checkbox (but your code will still run, so the event is not "cancelled"). It is in fact equivalent to: (not equivalent exactly, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473581/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false))

```
function(event) {
    console.log("run") // This is still run
    return false
});
```

So what `Event.preventDefault()` do is canceling default browser actions afterward. However, you cannot define default action on a custom `Event`. Then how is it still useful? Actually it is still useful on some special occasions. To demonstrate how it will work with custom `Event`, here is an example:

```js
const log = console.log;

const child = document.getElementById('child');
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
const child2 = document.getElementById('child2');
const parent2 = document.getElementById('parent2');


parent.addEventListener('newColor', function(e) {
    if (e.defaultPrevented) return;
    log('parent')
    this.style.color = e.detail.textColor;
})

child.addEventListener('newColor', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    log('child')
    this.style.color = e.detail.textColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor = e.detail.bgrColor;
})

parent2.addEventListener('newColorNotCancelable', function(e) {
    if (e.defaultPrevented) return; // does not return as event is not cancelable
    log('parentNotCancelable')
    this.style.color = e.detail.textColor;
})

child2.addEventListener('newColorNotCancelable', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    log('childNotCancelable')
    this.style.color = e.detail.textColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor = e.detail.bgrColor;
})


function changeColor() { 
    const myEvent = new CustomEvent('newColor', { 
        detail: { 
            textColor: 'red',
            bgrColor: 'blue',
        },
        cancelable: true,
        bubbles: true
    })    
    child.dispatchEvent(myEvent)
    const myEventNotCancelable = new CustomEvent('newColorNotCancelable', { 
        detail: { 
            textColor: 'red',
            bgrColor: 'blue',
        },
        cancelable: false,
        bubbles: true
    })
    child2.dispatchEvent(myEventNotCancelable)
}


changeColor()
```

```html
<p id="parent">this is the parent<span id="child"> THIS IS THE CHILD ELEMENT </span></p>
<p id="parent2">this is the parent<span id="child2"> THIS IS THE CHILD ELEMENT </span></p>
```

When you dispatch an event on `child` and `child2`, the event will propagate to their parents. By calling `Event.preventDefault()` on their children, you can make the parents know that the event has been "default prevented", if the `Event` is cancelable. It is similar to `Event.stopPropagation()` but it is more powerful because you can only skip certain DOM objects on the propagation chain.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a case or scenario where this would be useful. By the way, why did you say that `event.preventDefault()` prevents the rest of the statements from being executed? It doesn't. It only prevents the default browser action.

Comment: I meant default browser actions only.

Comment: The past tense of run is run or ran, not runned.

Answer (score 0):

We need `cancelable` field just to signal to some event listener whether the event can be cancelled. Yep, this is it. The point is that `preventDefault` has not effect if called for some event `e` and `e.cancelable === false`.

Here's one example. Imagine that you develop some js-library that communicates the lib's user using events (i.e. it's designed per the [EventBus pattern.](https://pierfrancesco-soffritti.medium.com/create-a-simple-event-bus-in-javascript-8aa0370b3969) )

The lib has a bunch of emitter functions. They emit custom events and execute some behaviour. Inside such emitter functions you might want to check whether the event emitted by the function was cancelled by some listener and change the function's behaviour accordingly. It may result to termination of the execution, some cleanup job, calling another function etc. What matters is that as a lib developer, you just let the user know what the lib does upon emitting some custom event `e`.

Now if the user wants to prevent the lib's behaviour he needs to subscribe for `e` and cancel it by calling `e.preventDefault`. Yes, you can call it at custom event. What it does is making the emitter's `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` method return `false` if the `e` is `cancelable` (not limited by that behaviour but that's what important for our example).

So why do we need the `cancelable` field? It comes into play in some more sophisticated scenaniors. Imagine that your lib has some behaviour which *can or cannot* be stopped or modified under some but *not every* scenario. Your lib is a black box. How would you let the user know the exact case? Yep, `e.cancelable === false`. As I've mentioned, the point is that `preventDefault` has no effect if called upon non cancelable event. Also there's no error risen. So by signaling `e.cancelable === false` you let the lib's user know that he has to resolve that other than by calling `e.preventDefault()`.