# Chrome: Auxiliary Click Event with Middle Mouse Button not fired if page is scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, custom-element

I try to detect a **middle mouse button click** on a HTML Custom Element by adding a listener for the [`auxclick`-Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) to it. As long as the page is not scrollable, this works totally fine in Chrome on a Win 10 machine.

As soon as the page is scrollable however, the event is not fired anymore and the standard bahavior of a middle click kicks in (scrolling the page by moving the mouse).

[image: scrolling triggered on middle click]

Does anyone know a way to work around this issue?

I've created a small [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nioe/pen/RwgoaKy) to demonstrate the behavior.
Without scrolling it just works fine, but if you uncomment line 2 in the CSS pane (`min-height: 200vh;`) the middle click triggers the scrolling behaviour.

Comment: is disabling the scroll is a valid answer? `document.getElementsByClassName("middle-click")[0].onmousedown = function(e) {  if (e.which === 2) {  console.log('Disabled'); return false;  }};`

Comment: Not really. I'm building a component library and don't know on what page these components are used. Therefore I cannot simply disable the scrolling.

Comment: note that its only disables scrolling by middle click press and only when it happens on your counter element. the scrolling can happen using mouse wheel and using middle mouse button outside that element

Comment: OR you can have the scroll and everything and also count the clicks by something like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("middle-click")[0].onmousedown = function(e) {  if (e.which === 2) {  console.log('Disabled'); const counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
    counter.innerText = Number.parseInt(counter.innerText) + 1;  }};`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now I got what you meant. Disabling the scrolling didn't do the trick, but when I call `preventDefault()` on the Mouse Down Event, it seems to work: https://codepen.io/nioe/pen/rNwWWZj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kudos to [iѕєρєня](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893439/i%D1%95%D1%94%CF%81%D1%94%D0%BD%D1%8F) for pointing me into the right direction.

If I listen to the `mousedown`-Event too, check if it has been fired from a middle click and then prevent the default behaviour, everything seems to work fine.

Checkout the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nioe/pen/rNwWWZj) for the full solution.

I still think that this is kind of a hack. If somebody knows why Chrome does behave like this, I would be glad, if you'd share it here. ;)

Comment: the `return false` and `preventDefault` seems to do the same but `return false` actually fires multiple things, [see here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473685/4893439)

Comment: i had to preventDefault for both mousedown and mouseup to make it work