# Issue on tab press using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, event-handling, jquery-events

I want to call `add()` function when I typed something in amount field and I press <kbd>tab</kbd> means it will call that. But the field next to amount is in readonly mode, so its not calling that function properly. I tried the code like below please anyone suggest me solution:

```
$('#price_1').on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
if( e.which == 9 ) {
var i=$('table tr').length;
html = '<tr>';
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" autocomplete="" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" id="productList" class="form-control autocomplete_txt item2" tabindex="0" value=""style="text-align:center;" autofocus></td>';
html += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" onkeypress="return IsNumber(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="price1 form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" onkeypress="return IsNumber(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>'; 
html += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>';
html += '</tr>';
$('table').append(html); 
$(".item2").autocomplete({
source: "https://www.duminex.com/product/search",
select: function( event, ui ) { 
var a = i - 1;
$('#id').val(ui.item.id); 
$('#price_' + a).val(ui.item.price);
}
});
i++;
}
});
<td><input type="text" tabindex="6" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumber(event);" onpaste="return false;" required="required" ></td>

<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required="required" ></td>
```

[image]

Comment: next field that is read-only does not depend on the current action. I think your function is not calling on pressing of tab.

Comment: Then any issue in function call @harsh

Comment: yeah function is calling what is happening on . If I press tab from previous field immediately its called.but I want function to be called once I press tab from amount field only

Comment: Is function is calling for all previous fields? except amount?

Comment: No.If I press tab from quantity to amount its immediately called

Comment: So, the problem is your function called for only one time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157536/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-harsh-patel).

Comment: try changing the tab index of input fields instead of "0" use sequence number like 201,202,203.. so on, based on required order.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, keyup gets called after the field loses focus. So registering on the amount field will not help. Reference:

[jQuery: keyup for TAB-key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4762594/6016779)

Also, is there any requirement like, the add() function has to happen on Tab press only and not if user clicks on anywhere outside the amount field  ? Or is it fine if it happens on the field losing focus ? Like clicking some where on the field also... Including TAB press...